# Explain example from Material UI v5

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Can someone explain to me what the spread operator is for in this example I took from material UI

the spread after the box-sizing.

```js
const Drawer = styled(MuiDrawer, { shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open' })(
    ({ theme, open }) => ({
        width: drawerWidth,
        flexShrink: 0,
        whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
        boxSizing: 'border-box',
        ...(open && {
            ...openedMixin(theme),
            '& .MuiDrawer-paper': openedMixin(theme),
        }),
        ...(!open && {
            ...closedMixin(theme),
            '& .MuiDrawer-paper': closedMixin(theme),
        }),
    }),
);
```

Comment: if the ```open``` value is ```true```, then ```openedMixin(theme),
            '& .MuiDrawer-paper': openedMixin(theme)``` are added to the styling, otherwise (open is ```false```), nothing is added.  The ```openedMixin``` i believe is a function that takes ```theme``` object as param and returns a object containing some styling (css rules).

Comment: The answer from @Medi actually helped me understand.